# Is it possible to alter a marked field´s field function with Word 2007 VBA?

Tags: vba, field, word-2007

i want do the following:

In Word 2007 place the Cursor on a field (or mark that field) and call a macro wich edit the field function of that field. (add some string).

I´m even grateful for some tipps what term to google.

I used the macro recorder and got following:

```
WordBasic.FormatField Field:="CITATION Gro05 \p 9 \l 1031"
```

Thats obvious creats a new field but where to go from here?

To get the selected field i thought about something like this:

```
If Selection.Type = WdFieldType Then ...
```

I hope someone give me some hints :) 
Bye Richard

Comment: wdFieldType isn't a type in itself. It's the name of the set of possible field types and you can find the list of possible values at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213727.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Selection.Range.Fields
```

Will give you the collection of fields in the current selection.